# Include PHP file in a CSS/PHP file?

Tags: php, html, css

I've made a CSS/PHP file , so the styles can be fetched from a database. However Im having trouble including another PHP file in this PHP/CSS. The usual include('newFile.php'); doesnt seem to be working!

```
<?php header("Content-type:text/css; charset:UTF-8" 
include('connect.php');

$newVar = $varFromConnectPHP 
?>

body 
{
background-color:<?php  echo $newVar; ?>
}
```

How do I include this second PHP file into this PHP/CSS file?

Cheers!

Comment: This is often a really bad plan as rendering CSS on the fly can be computationally expensive, especially if you're hooked up to a database. Consider rendering these out in advance using PHP and then minifying/compacting/packaging them as you should normally. If your stylesheet takes a long time to render your page might look totally broken until it finally kicks in.

Comment: Why does `include` not seem to be working? What happens? Do you get errors?

Comment: If I remove the include and then type say : $newVar = 'red'; , The CSS works fine. However as soon as I put the include in , it breaks all of the CSS for the page - even if I put   $newVar = 'red';

Comment: There's probably an error in the file you're including. Check *everything* for syntax errors. Have your error log open at all times to see what's being recorded. There could be a total disaster going on and you'd have no idea if you're not looking.

Comment: Also: `header("..."` is not valid syntax. You need the closing `);`.

Comment: What you posted is stitched with parse errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help , I am new to programming and forgot about error  checking in the Console as opposed to the IDE.

The problem seems to be my Connect.php was echo-ing a string , which was preventing the CSS from running for some reason..